# How to make a NPM package not available for Windows

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I am currently developing an open source project that needs to be published on NPM. It's a C++ Node addon, and it is only available for Linux and Mac.

I would like to know if it's possible to add a flag in `binding.gyp` returning an error if OS is Windows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `package.json` easily:

```
"os": ["!win32"]
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#os

I'm not sure if there's a nice way to do this in `binding.gyp`. You might be able to run something inside `"conditions": [['OS=="win"', ...` that will fail, but it would be a hack.